# Scoping inside of Module and Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, scoping

This is driving me nuts: I'm trying to control the parameters for a relatively large system of ODEs using Manipulate.

```
With[{todo =
  Module[
   {sol, ode, timedur = 40},
   ode = Evaluate[odes /. removeboundaries /. moieties];
   sol = NDSolve[Join[ode, init], vars, {t, 0, timedur}];
   Plot[Evaluate[c[1][t] /. parms] /. sol, {t, 0, timedur}]
   ],
 controls = 
  Sequence @@ 
   Table[{{parms[[i]][[1]], parms[[i]][[2]]}, 
     0, (3*parms[[i]][[2]])}, {i, 1, Length[parms]}]},
Manipulate[todo, controls, ContinuousAction -> False, 
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom]]
```

The solve step, in which sol is created, performs successfully. When trying to make a Plot from this however, I get all kinds of errors like

```
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`
```

Although NDSolve runs fine when Plot is commented out! Note that this code relies on global variables defined elsewhere in the script. I should also add that the code inside the Module[] works when copied to a fresh cell.

Could someone help me out?

Thanks!!

Comment: it seems to be fairly common sense, but it happens to be not so common ... Could you please post a self contained and running (or minimal not-running) example?

Answer (score 13):

Even without a minimual example, it is clear that you have a problem related to your use of `With` as the outer scoping construct. Please see the [answers to this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/8), particularly [mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/562/8).

> - Use `With` for local constants that you don't have to change subsequently.
> - Use `Module` for local variables that are local to that piece of code.
> - Use `Block` for local variables that are local to that sequence of evaluation.

You are defining `todo` to be a *constant*, and then trying to `Manipulate` it.

In addition, the `Module` outputs the graphic from the `Plot` as its output. It will be a `Graphics[]` object, which is not amenable to the kinds of parameter adjustment you seem to want.

My suggestion would be something along the lines of:

```
Module[{sol, ode, timedur = 40, controls}, 
  ode = Evaluate[odes /. removeboundaries /. moieties]; 
  sol = NDSolve[Join[ode, init], vars, {t, 0, timedur}]; 
  controls =  Sequence @@  
   Table[{{parms[[i]][[1]], parms[[i]][[2]]},  
     0, (3*parms[[i]][[2]])}, {i, 1, Length[parms], 1}]; 
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[c[1][t] /. parms] /. sol, {t, 0, timedur}] ,
 controls, ContinuousAction -> False,  ControlPlacement -> Bottom]]
```

Comment: The "use `With` for local constants" is a recommendation, but *not* a description of how `With` works. For example, the following code works just fine, setting `b` to `10`: `With[{a=b},a=10]`. And so does `With[{a=b^2},Manipulate[a,{b,0,1}]]`. What `With` *does* is to replace the symbol with the expression before evaluating that, with some fine points for nested scoping constructs. Note that due to how `With` works, the `Manipulate` does *not* try to manipulate `todo` in @Maarten's code (or `a` in my example above), but whatever `todo` is replaced with. And that seems indeed to be intended.

Comment: Thanks! My plan was to write a generic ODE solver with sliders for the parameters. I still haven't succeeded so I might be posting more questions on this.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem probably is that the right hand side of the `{todo = ...}` is evaluated before inserting into the Manipulate. Use `{todo := ...}` instead to disable premature evaluation. However if calculation of `ode` and `sol` does not involve `params` in any way (as your code suggests), you probably want to pre-evaluate that part, and only put the actual `Plot` command inside the `Manipulate`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I now understand that With[] defines constants, not variables. To compute `sol`, the parms have to be inserted into the odes by the Manipulate wrapper. I defined the odes as a constant - erroneously - and so couldn't manipulate them. I will try the := operator!